# netTcpBinding without Windows credentials?

Tags: wcf, credentials, nettcpbinding

I've got a machine-control application where I have a single client computer and five server boxes communicating on the machine subnet.  There is no domain controller. I would like to use [netTcpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731343%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to allow for reliability and transaction support.

Is is possible to use username / password authentication with this binding, when a domain controller is not present? I would prefer not to use a certificate as I don't want to manage certificates across 900 computers (150 machines) that will not be connected to the office LAN.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, of course - but only if you use Message security (rather than transport security). Define your binding configuration like so:

```
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="UserNameSecurity">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```

and then reference that binding configuration in your endpoints (on server and client):

```
 <endpoint address="....."
           binding="netTcpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="UserNameSecurity"
           contract="IMyService" />
```

Marc

UPDATE:
Ah, yes, on the server-side, you'll need a certificate to authenicate the service to the client calling it, and it's also used to encrypt+sign the messages. That's on the server only - clients need not install anything.

Configuration:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehavior>
    <behavior name="ServerInternet">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate
           findValue="MyServiceCertificate"
           storeLocation="LocalMachine"
           storeName="My"
           x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehavior>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="MyServiceInternet"
           behaviorConfiguration="ServerInternet">
     ....
  </service>
</services>
```

Make sure to install your server's certificate into the "Local Machine" folder on your server, under the "subject name" that you specify in your config.

Comment: So, that's what I had originally.  But, I get an exception asking for a service certificate: "The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredentials. "

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm.  That's what I suspected.  Thanks for confirming it.

Comment: In this approach is there any harm of using a self signed cert in production environment? If it's only used to encrypt messages but not to verify identity. When would you not use a self signed-cert for message encryption?

Comment: @marc_s -Why should he be required to have a server certificate? 
Shouldn't this work:
           myNetTcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
           myNetTcpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
           myNetTcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None;

Comment: @Stix you cannot set protection level to "None" in this scenario; it throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

There is something you can try first. Set serviceNegotiationCredentials to true:

```
<message negotiateServiceCredential="true"/>
```

This will create a secure conversation between your client and your service without a domain controller.

BUT, if there isn't any domain controller, the client doesn't trust your service, so it will fail.

So you should set the expected [identity of the service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733130.aspx). You can find that in the WSDL of your service. By default, if you are hosted on IIS, it seems to be:

```
<client>
    <endpoint>
        <identity>
            <servicePrincipalName value="host/NETWORKSERVICE"></servicePrincipalName>
        </identity>
    </endpoint>
</client>
```

I don't think you'll need it, but maybe you'll have to allow anonymous logon on the service side:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
        <serviceCredentials>
            <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="true"/>
        </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think that the negotiateServiceCredential does not exist for the netTcpBinding.  I will likely go down the certificate path, since that seems (relatively) straight forward.